# PHP memcache warning error

Tags: php, cron

Basically i am trying to read the FTP files from serve via cron job.

I am getting following error

> Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (memcache). Please
>   verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct
>   (tcp://***.***.*.*:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15)
>   in Unknown on line 0

I don't have idea why i am getting this error. Any idea what is missing there

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend updating your php.ini to use file based caching unless memcache is what you need.

Change session.save_handler to files.

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

Memcache is typically used when you have multiple servers that need to share the same session (a.k.a behind a load balancer)